# Установка Node Package Manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

При попытке установить npm строка говорит, что версия Node.js 9 не поддерживается npm.

Нужно откатиться до предыдущей версии Нода? Если да, то как это сделать?

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в место срасибо, можно приять ответ, это лучше спасибо.. если  не оставили вопрос без внимания, не  нада оставлять  ответ без внимания...

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить несколько версий NodeJs. Установите  nvm пакет ссылка на оф.
страницу на  [GitHub](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). 
Эта команда установит менеджер версии

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash

После установки менеджера версий node можно устанавливать командой

> nvm install [просто номер версии без квадратных кавычек]

Но лучше установить какой-нибудь пакет node по умолчанию командой

> nvm alias default [просто номер версии без квадратных кавычек]

После  устанавливайте любой пакет nodjs и меняйте нужную версию командой

> nvm use [просто номер версии без квадратных кавычек]

Comment: Спасибо большое!